# Connect Jenkins to git on team foundation server

Tags: jenkins, tfs, jenkins-blueocean

I'm creating a new pipeline in Jenkins Blue Ocean and when trying to commit changes changes to git getting this error after several minutes

[image]

The git server itself is OK, I'm able to push/pull changes from command line. Jenkins itself also works fine with github.

Comment: for the push/pull did you use ssh?

Comment: Yes I did. It works fine from my computer. Jenkins is also hosted on my computer for now but still getting this...

Comment: Do you use GitHub or TFS to store your repo? If use TFS, which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce your issue on my side, you may check my steps here:

1. Start to create a pipeline and  select `Git`.

[image]

2. Clone the SSH in your TFS repo and type it in `Repository URL`:

[image]

3. Register the public SSH key in your TFS and click `Create Pipeline`:

[image]